# Nested Conditional Statement Works, but Combines Conditional Statement Doesn't - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have a piece of code where I have solved a problem, but I don't know why my solution works, which I'm finding almost as frustrating as when something doesn't work.

Basically I have an SVG viewbox that I've resized with JS for big screens.

This SVG viewbox is only on one page of my site, page1.

I have a conditional statement where if the users in on page1 and the window is 1920px or larger the viewbox resizes.

I have achieved this with a nested if statement.

```
if (page1) {

    if (window.innerWidth > 1919) {

        // set SVG viewbox for screens larger than 1920px

    } else {

        // keep normal viewbox dimensions.

    }

}
```

When I orginally tried this, I did it as one if statement with two conditions, and although this worked on page1 it threw an error in the console when I wasn't on page1.

Why does it throw an error on pages that aren't `page1` when there is one combined condition, and not when the conditions are nested? The error I was getting was basically saying the SVG element doesn't exist. I'm very confused.

```
if (page1 && window.innerWidth > 1919) {

// set SVG viewbox for screens larger than 1920px

} else {

// keep normal viewbox dimensions.

}
```

Comment: Those aren't equivalent. The first has the possibility of nothing happening; in the second one something will always happen.

Comment: People have down-marked the question without reading it properly.  When I'm on page2 (therefore not page 1) of the site and the window is less than 1920, the code still executes with the 2nd version of the code and throws an error in the console because it can't find the SVG (which is only on page1).  Surely this shouldn't happen because the code is set to only fire if it is page1 && the window is bigger than 1920 ?

Comment: Be clear. *What* code is executing‽

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of what your code means: in the first version, if it *is* `page1`, then you either change the size or you maintain the default size. If it *isn't* `page1`, you do *nothing*.

In the second case, if it's `page1` and the window is big, you use the big viewbox. If it's *either* not `page1` *or* the page isn't large enough, you use the default size.

They're just not the same.

Comment: Oh yes I understand that, it's just I don't know why it throws an error on pages that aren't page1.  I mean, both conditions don't return true if I'm on page2 and the window is < 1920, so I thought the code wouldn't execute. But it does, and it throws and error (because the SVG graphic is only on page1). This is where I'm confused.

Comment: @TheChewy the code in the `else` clause runs if you're not on page 1 *or* if the window is smaller than 1920px. Only one of the conditions in an `&&` expression have to be false to make the whole thing false.